# How can I test a build while developing a feature without updating to the testflight or any other testers

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, testflight, fastlane, xcode11

I am developing an app. I need to test my build before handling to other testers. How can I automate that and how can I build this.

Note: Now I am using testflight to upload (fastlane) my build to the testers. But If I upload this the other testers giving feedbacks. Here I need to test it thoroughly in real device and then I need to submit under testflight.

Can anyone have any idea how can I test it internally before giving the build to testers?

Also, If I archive the file via Xcode to generate ipa file does it make any certificate issues while generating the ipa and installing in real device.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to build an ipa file for Ad-hoc deployment since you want to test it internally and if you are in a hurry.

[image]

If you have more time. You can update your iOS fastlane Fastfile to increment the build number using "increment_build_number" to prevent override:

```
  desc "Push a new release build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "sampleAppFLwk.xcodeproj")
    match(type: "appstore")
    cocoapods
    build_app(workspace: "sampleAppFLwk.xcworkspace", scheme: "sampleAppFLwk")
    upload_to_testflight(
      skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
    )
    clean_build_artifacts
  end
```

Comment: My question I have time too. But before handling the build to my testers I need to verify entirely in real device. How can i test it in real device and then only I need to generate build

Comment: As mention above, build an adhoc ipa and install it to a physical device.. You have to build it anyways...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: XCode**

You can make a release build from within XCode and run it on local device. Make sure your scheme is configured for release. Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Info, set Build Configuration to Release, and uncheck Debug executable. Note that you need the correct certificates to make a release build like this.

I don't know how you could automate this however, so solution 2 might be better and definitely more scalable.

**Solution 2: TestFlight Groups**

TestFlight lets you have multiple test groups. This means a freshly submitted build doesn't necessarily have to be visible to all testers. Read more about creating groups and adding groups to a build [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd1bda3d0c)

Hope this helps :)